# Android Studio: Different Buttons With Same ID?

Tags: android

I have a special button that appears in multiple areas in the same activity that has a resetting functionality. Since AS didn't allow me to declare multiple instances of that button in the same activity with the same ID name, I was wondering if it was possible to recreate that functionality in a different way.

What I have now is 3 different buttons, appropriately named `Reset`, with the IDs of `reset1`,`reset2`,`reset3`;

To handle their use, I just have a switch statement that looks like this (pseudo):

```
switch(button){
  case reset1:
  case reset2:
  case reset3:
     doSomething();
     break;
}
```

To me, it would appear simpler  to just use a single ID for all those buttons. Why can't I do that? What are the risks? Is there any alternative to the method I'm currently using?

Comment: You cannot use a single ID because ID's originate from a generated `R` file. So, instead of risking that everything crashes, the Android engineers simply prohibited you to even try it.

Comment: Because an `ID` belong to `one` view per viewgroup. If you want to do that, you should use `android:tag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single method in your activity and then reference that method with each of your button via the **onClick** attribute of button. Like this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/reset1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:onClick="onReset"/> //Check this
<Button
        android:id="@+id/reset2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:onClick="onReset"/>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/reset3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:onClick="onReset"/>
```

Now in your MyActivity.java create onReset method as:

```
public void onReset(View v){
//do something.
}
```

Remember that the method needs to be public and have View as a parameter.
You don't even need to assign id's to these buttons if not needed for another purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that switch statement, you can assign the same OnClickListener to all three buttons:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
findViewById(R.id.reset1).setOnClickListener(listener);      
findViewById(R.id.reset2).setOnClickListener(listener);
findViewById(R.id.reset3).setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: In situations where I have to handle many buttons I find it really tedious to assign an `OnClickListener` to every button, that's why I use `switch()` instead.

Comment: @JohanZ do you instead mean "instead of doing that, my Activity implements OnClickListener and I just `setOnClickListener(this);` for every button?

Comment: Sort of. It doesn't implement `OnClickListener()`, but a custom method I call from every button set up in the XML.

Comment: I don't like that 'android:onclick' as you don't know in the code, who calls that method... if you can use [butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), you can easily bind multiple IDs to one method. And no need to use onclicklisteners.